# Is it possible to store the current colorscheme into a session?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, sessions

As title. I have to use some colorscheme to make my reading experience better on certain filetype. I have made an auto session plugin myself but I don't know how to store the colorscheme info I'm currently on into it. Is there any native way for doing so?

My trying: The following are the only two lines that might be related to what will be stored into the session:

```
vim.opt.ssop:append({ 'localoptions', 'globals' })
vim.opt.ssop:remove({ 'buffers' })
```

As I assumed `colorscheme` is some global variable. But by grepping inside the session file created, I didn't find any string `colorscheme`.

Might not be related, but I'm using NeoVim.

Comment: @romainl: I have checked `:h ssop` before, but I'm not sure about which one is related to colorscheme. I have updated my question.

Comment: Oops, it seems that `:h ssop` doesn't help with this problem. I don't think other options that I haven't appended are related to `colorscheme`. Maybe you should try your attempt before answering people's questions.

Comment: Comment != answer. Also I wanted to make sure you did due diligence before asking your question.

Comment: The edits seem to have clarified the question. @romainl asking for clarification and pointing to resources are fine, but please avoid any condescension or suggestion that the OP cannot read… that is quite rude. (Perhaps "Do you need help _interpreting_ these help documents" is better?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just made a post on another forum and got some practical advice there, and finally achieved the feature I want and added it to my plugin. Here is how I did that:

1. Let me quote a part of the advice first:

   > I use a session manager known as possession. Possession lets me saves the session data in a **json file** and allows me to save custom data as well. It also provides hooks to [...]
2. So here is a part of my implementation: (For simplicity, only posting write process here)

   1. These are some utils to abstract the json-write process:

   ```lua
   local function write_to_project_json(data)
     if type(data) ~= 'table' then return false end
     local fp = io.open(get_project_json_path(), 'w+')
     if not fp then return false end
     fp:write(vim.json.encode(data))
     fp:close()
     return true
   end
   ```

   2. Then you can do something like this:

   ```lua
   -- store data
   local succeed, data = get_or_create_project_file_data()
   if succeed and type(data) == 'table' then
     data.colors_name = vim.g.colors_name
     write_to_project_json(data)
   end
   ```

Comment: Really impressive (for me)